# Is there a variant of Control.BeginInvoke which works before/after the handle is destroyed?

Tags: .net, winforms, asynchronous, controls, begininvoke

I have a control which displays the state of an underlying asynchronous object. The object raises events, which arrive at the form, where they are essentially queued and eventually called using BeginInvoke.

A problem arises when the control is disposed. Because things are happening asynchronously, meaning it is always possible that an event callback is queued during disposal, I sometimes get an InvalidOperationException (Invoke or BeginInvoke cannot be called on a control until the window handle has been created.).

This is not the behavior I want. I want the callback to execute even if the control has been disposed (even if that causes an exception in the callback; that's a far more useful exception to me!). I want to handle the disposed state behavior in each callback (usually just skip if disposed, but sometimes not [eg. one control logs events (optionally to a file) and I don't want to lose log data!].).

Is there a method that works the way I want? Can I write a non-brittle one myself?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try `SynchronizationContext.Current` instead.  This has the `Post` and `Send` members which *roughly* map to `BeginInvoke` and `Invoke` on `Control`.  These operations will continue to function so long as the UI thread is alive vs. a specific control.

The type `SynchronizationContext` is not specific to WinForms and solutions leveraging it will be portable to other frameworks such as WPF.

For example.

BeginInvoke Code

```
void OnButtonClicked() {
  DoBackgroundOperation(this); 
}

void DoBackgroundOperation(ISynchronizedInvoke invoke) {
  ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate { 
    ...
    delegate.BeginInovke(new MethodInvoker(this.BackgroundOperationComplete), null);
  });
}
```

SynchronizationContext code

```
void OnButtonClicked() {
  DoBackgroundOperation(SynchronizationContext.Current);
}

void DoBackgroundOperation(SynchronizationContext context) {
  ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate {
    ...
    context.Post(delegate { this.BackgroundOperationComplete() }, null);
  });
}
```

Comment: Could you give a usage example? Is it a member of the control or a global thing?

Comment: Thanks, this is really useful. It will probably work in lots of other scenarios, too.

Comment: I'm a bit unclear on how I take a control and get its synchronization context if the handle might not exist.