# Is there an event when the window handle is destroyed

Tags: .net, winforms, window-handles

Since the destruction of a window handle disables the invoke mechanism, I do want to unsubscribe to an background-worker that notifies me.

So is there an event that is fired shortly before the window handle of a windows form is closed.

( I have seen this [Is there a variant of Control.BeginInvoke which works before/after the handle is destroyed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4513761/is-there-a-variant-of-control-begininvoke-which-works-before-after-the-handle-is) but I do not like it and if possible want to avoid it... )

TIA

Mario

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`HandleDestroyed`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.handledestroyed.aspx) event (or override the `OnHandleDestroyed` method).

Comment: Unless you're in some kind of lock which is being respected both in your background worker, and in any code which will destroy the handle, there's still a race here that the handle can be destroyed after this function returns false, and before `BeginInvoke` is attempted

Comment: thanks! this is really hard to achieve since i get intereupted even between a ´IsHandleCreated´ and the ´Invoke´ call....